# Getting the Contents of a File and Putting it into a String in C

Tags: c, file, while-loop, file-io, printf

I am trying to make a function in C that takes the contents of a file and returns the contents as a string.  I got it to works except for one odd detail.  This is the current code:

```
char *getFileContents(const char *filePath) {
    if (filePath == NULL) return NULL;
    char buffer[1000];
    char character;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen(filePath, "r");

    while (character != EOF) {
        count++;
        character = fgetc(f);
        printf("%c\n", character);
    }
    count--;
    fclose(f);

    FILE *F = fopen(filePath, "r");
    char *str = (char*) malloc ( sizeof(char) * (count + 1 ) );
    char *line = fgets(buffer, 1000, F);
    while (line != NULL) {
        strcat(str, line);
        line = fgets(buffer, 1000, F);
    }
    fclose(F);
    return str;
}
```

In the first while loop, I added a printf statement for error checking that I do not need anymore.  The function works fine with the printf statement but whenever I comment it out or remove it I get a segmentation fault.  I've used gdb to debug and try to find the issue.
I can step through the whole function but the moment it reaches the `return str` at the end I get a segmentation fault.  I'm not sure why I'm experiencing this problem.

Comment: You never initialize `character` to any value, so the first time `while (character != EOF)` executes, it is reading an uninitialized value (which might accidentally be EOF)

Comment: `fgetc` returns an int.  If you assign it to a char variable, you cannot reliably distinguish between EOF and data.

Answer (score 0):

The commenting of a line causing a segmentation fault is the manifestation of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The initial comparison of `character` with `EOF` reads an uninitialized, garbage value.

```
char character;
/* ... */
while (character != EOF) {
/* ... */
```

The results of this program cannot be reasoned about after this occurs. A random SIGSEGV is par for the course.

Additionally, `fgetc` returns an `int`. `EOF` is a negative value, and cannot be properly represented if [`char` is unsigned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types).

Try changing your loop construct.

```
int character;
/* ... */
while (EOF != (character = fgetc(f))
    count++;
```

Note, you should also check that the return value from `fopen` was not `NULL`, and react accordingly.

```
FILE *f = fopen(filePath, "r");

if (!f) {
    perror(filePath);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the structure of the while loop to `while (EOF != (character = fgetc(f)) count++;` like you had suggested but I got different errors.  When compiled the program, it produced the double free or corruption error and aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @Arnold In that case, please update your question to include a complete, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that contains your `main` function and the appropriate `#include` directives. See Jeremy's answer for further issues with this current function, but there are likely more problems with your program as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you never initialize the memory buffer returned by `malloc()` -- you are apparently expecting it to be all-zeros (or at least start with a 0-byte) so that you can fill it in with calls to `strcat()`; but `malloc()` doesn't guarantee the contents of the memory it returns will be zeroed-out, so you are likely starting with some garbage-bytes already present in the `str` buffer, which means that as you add more bytes from the file, you will likely write past the end of the buffer and invoke undefined behavior (and likely crash).

The simple fix would be to do a `str[0] = '\0';` after the call to `malloc()` (or if you're paranoid, you could do a full `memset(str, 0, count+1);`).  Or alternatively you could allocate the memory with a call to [calloc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) rather than malloc(), as `calloc()` does guarantee that the returned buffer will be all zero-initialized bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the first while loop that counts the number of characters in the file and moved it to a different function.  The function I moved it to will be responsible for counting the characters.  This way I would only need one `fopen` and `fclose` statement in the `getFileContents` function.  This solved my problem and everything is working as intended.